# Embed a link to a local folder in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, href

Hi I am running a local Shiny app. I want to embed a link in the UI which will open the path of the local folder where the output files will be created.

```
 showModal(modalDialog(title ="Output:",
                    helpText(a("Click Here To Download The Output",href="C:\\Output\\",target="_blank")),
                    actionButton("close", "Exit"),footer = NULL,
                    size = c("m"), easyClose = FALSE))
```

The link pops up in the browser after running the code but when I click on the link, it doesn't open any folder. Please adivse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, here is how you make it work -

1. Get your ipv4 address using `ipconfig` from command prompt
2. Build the link using the IP Address. For example -

If your file is in `C:\\Output\\`, replace it with `file://<ipaddress>/c$/Output/`

3. If it still doesn't work, make sure sharing is turned on for that folder - `Right Click` --> `Properties` --> `Sharing` --> `Advanced Sharing` --> Make sure `Share this folder` option is checked